# Implicit derivative of $(x - y)^2 = x + y - 1$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

I changed the function from:

**$(x - y)^2 = x + y - 1$** to:

**$(x^2) - (y^2) - x - y = -1$**  All I did was move the variables to one side.

When moved, I get **$\displaystyle \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{2x - 1}{2y + 1}$**

Otherwise, I get **$\displaystyle \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{2y - 2x + 1} {2y - 2x - 1}$**

Anyone else having this problem? And which one is correct?

Comment: You can find some good starting points on how to format mathematics on the site [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020). [This AMS reference](ftp://ftp.ams.org/ams/doc/amsmath/short-math-guide.pdf) is very useful.

Comment: You don't have to move the variables to one side to take the derivative, you can take the derivative as is and then solve for $\frac{dy}{dx}$.

Answer (score 2):

But $(x-y)^2 \ne x^2-y^2$ it is $x^2-2xy+y^2$

Comment: Oh! Well now I feel a bit stupid for not seeing that. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

$$(x - y)^2 = x + y - 1$$
$$2(x-y)(1-y')=1+y'$$
$$2(x-y)-1=y'(2(x-y)+1)$$
$$y'=\frac{2(x-y)-1}{2(x-y)+1}=\frac{2y-2x+1}{2y-2x-1}$$